# Resize icons for Portrait vs Landscape orientation for Navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, orientation

For a mobile application we are using bootstrap navbar with menu options. It looks like this in portrait and landscape respectively .

Portrait:

[image]

Landscape:

[image]

What I am trying to do is to get the li elements inside the navbar unifromly distributed in any orientation.I tried to give left and right padding for the li items inside the navbar so that they are uniformly spaced even after orientation is changed. The problem would be if I add more li elements or remove a few of them they are not uniformly distributed. Any other options with which I can get the icons inside the navbar uniformly distributed in any orientation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using flexbox?

```
ul{
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: space-around;
  -ms-flex-pack: space-around;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/scrfrmLk/

Answer (score 1):

This is somewhat trivial with [flexbox](https://scotch.io/tutorials/a-visual-guide-to-css3-flexbox-properties).

Add `display: flex` to the container. Then, you can achieve the uniform horizontal spacing with `justify-content: space-between`. If you also want to vertically center them, add `align-items: center`.

Note that `space-between` keeps the first and last elements at the sides, while `space-around` does not. Choose whichever you prefer.

An example:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: #333;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.icon {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0 10px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="icon"></div>
  <div class="icon"></div>
  <div class="icon"></div>
  <div class="icon"></div>
  <div class="icon"></div>
</div>
```